# Laravel Routing issue for fetch images

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, routes

I am doing Upload gallary in laravel. After completion of uploading, I am trying to display Images on browser. Here the problem is, I uploaded images on UPLOADS Directory outside of (parllel) PUBLIC folder. While fetching that image, the path is **wesbite.com/Uploads/xxx.jpg** . here Uploads treat as Routing path. So I need to ignore routing for that. Can anybody suggest please.

I tried with .htaccess **RewriteRule ^(uploads) - [L]**   . But it completley ignores the Uploads directory.

Comment: the RewriteRule ^(path/to/folder) - [L] works for me.
Try to put something wrong inside the .htaccess ( you should get 500 server error ) to check if it is loaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The public folder is the webroot, anything outside of it cannot be accessed via the browser. If you want the images to be accessed to be accessed through something like `/uploads/xxx.jpg` you'll need a directory called `uploads` within the `public` directory.

Unfortunately that's the way that it works, you can view things on the web that are outside the webroot, although you could do something like, having a controller and method that uses something like `file_get_contents()` to load it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a case before that I was having a redirect loop problem because one of my routes is the same as the name of a directory in `public`. Edit your `public/.htaccess`

```
# Redirect trailing slashes but only if the directory is non existent
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

# Handle front controller but only if file is non existent
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d (comment this out otherwise the url will route to the     directory content listing not your preferred controller action)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```